# passing value from form to modal box in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

My view Page :

```
        <form id="myForm" >
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker pull-right" name="from_date" placeholder="From"> // want this value in my modal box
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker pull-right" name="to_date" placeholder="To"> // want this value in my modal box

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <br/>
          <center><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="search_sale_return()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Create New Stock</button></center> // on this click call the modal
          </div>
          </form>
```

JavaScript

```
 <!-- Search sale return -->
              function search_sale_return()
              {   
            save_method = 'sale_return';
           $('#form_sale_return')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
       $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
       $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string


    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('PharmacyController/search_sale_return')?>/"     + 1, // bring value from database via controller in json_encode form 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        $('[name="ph_name"]').val(data.from_date);


        $('#modal_sale_return').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when  complete loaded
        $('.modal-title').text('Sale return'); // Set title to Bootstrap     modal title

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
 });

 }
```

Modal

```
<!-- Bootstrap Receptionist modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_sale_return" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Stock</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form">
            <form action="#" id="form_sale_return" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="ph_id"/> 
                <div class="form-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Medicine Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="ph_name" placeholder="Medicine Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <input name="ph_clinic_id"  value="<?php echo $userinfo['id']; ?>" type="hidden">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <br/>
                <table id="table_account" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Transaction Id</th>
                            <th>Patient Id</th>
                            <th>Ammount payed</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

This is my code , here i would like to get the value from form and than use it in my controller via javascript code and get json data and display it on my modal box

My problem :: on submit either i get link to controller or my modal (i wanna go to controller and from there i wanna go to modal in just one click button)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#modal_sale_return').modal();
```

to manually open the modal

Sending form data to controller :

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
var ajaxForm = $(this)[0];
var formData = new FormData(ajaxForm);

$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (result) {

    },
    error : function() {

    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Fast example:

FORM:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar">
            </i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker pull-right" name="from_date" placeholder="From" /> // want this value in my modal box
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar">
            </i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker pull-right" name="to_date" placeholder="To" /> // want this value in my modal box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br/>
        <center>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
            </i> Create New Stock
            </button>
        </center>
        // on this click call the modal
    </div>
</form>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Receptionist modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_sale_return" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h3 class="modal-title">Stock</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body form">
              <form action="#" id="form_sale_return" class="form-horizontal">
                  <input type="hidden" value="" name="ph_id"/> 
                  <div class="form-body"> 

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label col-md-3">Medicine Name</label>
                          <div class="col-md-9">
                              <input name="ph_name" placeholder="Medicine Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                              <input name="ph_clinic_id"  value="<?php echo $userinfo['id']; ?>" type="hidden">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                      </div>  

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <br/>
                  <table id="table_account" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Transaction Id</th>
                              <th>Patient Id</th>
                              <th>Ammount payed</th>
                              <th>Time</th>
                              <th>Action</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>  

                  </table>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('form#myForm').on('submit',function(event) {
    //get value
    event.preventDefault();
    var from_date = $(this).find('input[name="from_date"]').val();
    var to_date = $(this).find('input[name="to_date"]').val();

    //get data $_GET
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('PharmacyController/search_sale_return')?>", // bring value from database via controller in json_encode form 
        type: "GET",
        data: {from_date: from_date,to_date:to_date},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            var modal = $('#modal_sale_return').modal('show');
            modal.find('[name="ph_name"]').val(data.name);
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Sale return');
            modal.find('#form_sale_return').trigger('reset');
            modal.find('.help-block').empty();
            modal.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            //etc           

            //save in modal
            $(modal).on('submit','form#form_sale_return',function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var form = $(this);
              var ph_name = form.find('[name="ph_name"]').val();
              //etc
              $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('PharmacyController/save')?>",
                type: "post",
                data:{ph_name:ph_name},
                success: function(response) {
                  alert('SUCCESS')
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                  alert('ERROR');
                }
              });
            });
            $('#modal_sale_return').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when  complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Sale return'); // Set title to Bootstrap     modal title

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });

  });
});
</script>
```

I not tested... you try :)